# Calculated column is not being crawled

Tags: calculated-column, sharepoint-search

I have a calculated site column AlertSortOrder, which I added to a list. I created a managed property nvAlertSortOrder (sortable, searchable, queryable, retrievable) mapped to the corresponding crawled property (ows_AlertSortOrder). 
The problem - I am unable to filter/sort by that managed property, and when I check the raw search results using search api:

`/searchcenter/_api/search/query?querytext='my unique list item title'&selectproperties=nvAlertSortOrder`

that property is null.

Any ideas?

Comment: Have you done a full crawl since you added the columm

Comment: I have perform a full crawl

Comment: I have the same problem. Any solution mate? thanks

Comment: I haven't found a solution. We ended up not using calc field

Answer (score -1):

Beyond performing a full-crawl (as Dave suggested), while having used the field on few items, you would also need to promote it as Managed Property, by default being just Crawled property, while settings its attributes, e.g. [searchable](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj219667.aspx#proc5) - via the managed properties in SP-CA, as well as update the settings of your web parts to include it in results.

Comment: As I stated in my question, I did create a managed property mapped to teh crawled property, and i made it searchable, retrievable, sortable, etc.